# replace text with input

Tags: jquery

I have the markup like that:

```
<div class="outer">
  <a class="btn">
   <img src="btnImg.jpg" />
  </a>
  Some Title
</div>
```

Now, I need to replace the text (**Some Title** thing) with a textbox that contains the current title. 
I've tried that:

```
$(".outer").append("<input value='"+$(".outer").text()+"'></input>");
$(".outer").text("");
```

It puts a textbox with an empty string. I tried to store the text in a temporary variable, I tried to clone the entire outer div and then get the text, and empty the text in the original div. Anyway whatever I do, after I clear the text, input value also becomes empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply store the text in a variable and then clear the div prior to appending the input.

```
var $outer = $(".outer");
var text = $.trim($outer.text());

$outer.empty();
$outer.append("<input value='" + text + "'></input>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SJeyf/2/

UPDATE based on comment (retain image, etc.):

```
var $outer = $(".outer");
var text = $.trim($outer.text());

var $textNode = $(".outer").contents()
                    .filter(function(){
                        return this.nodeType == 3 
                               && $.trim($(this).text()).length;   
                    }).eq(0)

$textNode.replaceWith("<input value='" + text + "'></input>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SJeyf/4/

NOTE: There may be a better way to grab the correct text node, but this seems to work.

Comment: and I'm gonna lose the anchor and whatnot

Answer (score 1):

Yay, found it to work! Example :[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpgZK/2/)

```
var text = $('.outer').text();
$('.outer').text('').append($('<input>').val(text));
```

Comment: `this` in this context is not `.outer`, you're missing a `)` and if you fix those problems this will be equivalent to the original code.

Comment: 30 seconds before I posted according to the timestamps, caching issue I guess.

Answer (score 1):

wow... that was an interesting excursion...

```
$(".outer")[0].lastChild.textContent = "blah";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9uQtJ/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your last JavaScript statement. You replace all content of `<div class="outer">…</div>` with an empty string. The previous inserted input element is just removed.

You need to select only the text child nodes of `<div class="outer">…</div>` to remove *"Some Title"*. Take a look at this question for how to do this: [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/vsLac/

```
var text = $.trim($('.outer').text());
$('.outer').append($('<input>', {value: text}));
```

Comment: He doesn't want the text there anymore

Comment: @Phil -- and what about the link and the image?